# Visual Studio SDK: Whole line suggestions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, vs-extensibility, vssdk

How can I work with the new AI-based suggestion feature using Visual Studio Extensibility? I'm referring to the following new feature (in VS2022?):

[image]

I can use `IAsyncCompletionSource` and stuff to add custom entries to the auto-complete list, but I'm looking for the light-grey whole line suggestion (`string.IsNullOrEmpty...`) that appears in the above image. If possible, I'd like to provide my own suggestion to replace the built-in suggestion.